# SQL - Get avg counts by device type

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the average number of events by day per device. I've got it mostly working, but can't get the GROUP BY device to spit out all the devices.

Data looks like this:

```
 user_id    device  attribution event_date
 1  Desktop Organic         2019-09-02 16:21:44
 2  Mobile  Organic         2019-09-03 16:22:25
 3  Desktop Direct          2019-09-04 16:22:27
 4  Tablet  Organic         2019-09-04 16:22:29
 5  Desktop Email           2019-09-04 16:22:31
 6  Desktop Email           2019-09-04 16:25:59
 7  Desktop Organic         2019-09-05 16:21:44

 SELECT dt.device AS AcquisitionType, AVG(dt.events) AS AverageEvents
 FROM ( SELECT u.device,
     COUNT (u.event_date) AS events
     FROM users AS u
     GROUP BY DATE(event_date)
     ) AS dt
 GROUP BY dt.device
 ;
```

Not getting any errors. everything is working except I can't get the results to be grouped by device.

Comment: It should be `GROUP BY u.device, DATE(event_date)` in the subquery. But there is already a better answer.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel but MySQL would have added that, no? (It either adds it and the query succeeds cos the select list references it, or it doesn't add it because it's in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode and then the query gets an error)

Comment: @CaiusJard No it doesn't. With `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` it would raise an error. Without OFGB it will return one row per date with an "arbitary" device.

Comment: Looks like another good reason to run in OFGB mode !

Comment: Running without `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is such a disservice to new users of SQL as this query should have raised an error per ANSI standards.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't actually find anything wrong with your query,
once I added `GROUP BY u.device,DATE(event_date)` on the inner query because my MySQL runs in only_full_group_by, but from @PaulSpiegel's comment it seem that because you only grouped on the date, and your mysql isn't "only full group by" mode, then mysql just tossed all your distinct device info out in order to get the query to succeed. I suppose conceptually mysql rewrote your query so that instead of `select device, count..` on the inner, it was more like `select max(device), count ...`

I strongly recommend you activate "only full group by" mode, which would have required you to use device in the group by because you'd used it in the select list

As an aside I offer this optimization:

You want the total number of events (`COUNT(*)`) per device (`GROUP BY device`)  divided by the total number of distinct days (`COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(u.event_date))`) the device has been raising events. Desktop has 5 events over 3 distinct days, so expecting about 1.667. One per day for the other two:

```
SELECT 
  u.device AS AcquisitionType,
  COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(u.event_date)) AS AverageEvents
FROM users u
GROUP BY u.device;
```

I made this fiddle to demo:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  `user_id` INTEGER,
  `device` VARCHAR(15),
  `sc` VARCHAR(15),
  `event_date` timestamp
);

INSERT INTO users
  (`user_id`, `device`, `sc`, `event_date`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Desktop','Organic', '2019-09-02 16:21:44'),
  ('2', 'Mobile', 'Organic','2019-09-03 16:22:25'),
  ('3', 'Desktop','Direct', '2019-09-04 16:22:27'),
  ('4', 'Tablet', 'Organic','2019-09-04 16:22:29'),
  ('5', 'Desktop','Email', '2019-09-04 16:22:31'),
  ('6', 'Desktop','Email', '2019-09-04 16:25:59'),
  ('7', 'Desktop','Organic', '2019-09-05 16:21:44');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
    SELECT 
      u.device AS AcquisitionType,
      COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(u.event_date)) AS AverageEvents
    FROM users u
    GROUP BY u.device;

| AcquisitionType | AverageEvents |
| --------------- | ------------- |
| Desktop         | 1.6667        |
| Mobile          | 1             |
| Tablet          | 1             |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9sgCoW29J8uKJpTmFhJNkq/0)

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what's happening in this line, so I can understand: 
     COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(u.event_date)) AS AverageEvents

Comment: Picking on Desktop as a device, the `COUNT(*)` will be 5, hopefully fairly obvious why on that one - COUNT just accumulates a 1 for any valid non null data and 0 for null. it takes no notice of the data itself, hence why count(*), count(0), count(date) all return 5. COUNT DISTINCT is more subtle, it examines the data itself. if we strip the time off the datetime using DATE() function, we get 3 distinct dates for desktop - the 2nd, 3rd and 4th of sep. as a result count distinct returns 3 (without distinct it would return 5) and this gives us 5 divided by 3 or 1.667 events per day for desktop

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one step, with no subqueries:

```
SELECT u.device AS AcquisitionType,
       SUM(u.events)  / COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(u.event_date)) AS AverageEvents
FROM users u
GROUP BY u.device;
```